# How do I catch this exception in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception, selenium-webdriver, net-http, rb-appscript

I'm a ruby beginner so bear with me.

I am using the selenium-webdriver and rb-appscript gems to do some webscraping. The navigation to websites seems to be driven by the Net::Http object, which has a rbuf_fill method.

Running the following code:

```
sites = File.open("sites.txt", "r") if File::exists?( "sites.txt" )

    if sites != nil
       while (line = sites.gets)

              driver.switch_to.default_content

          begin
                 driver.navigate.to line

          rescue Exception
                 line = line.split.join("\n")
                 puts line + " caused a timeout."
          end

       end

...
```

Produces this error:

```
/opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:140:in `rescue in rbuf_fill': Timeout::Error (Timeout::Error)
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2219:in `read_status_line'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2208:in `read_new'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1191:in `transport_request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1177:in `request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1170:in `block in request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1168:in `request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:73:in `response_for'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:41:in `request'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:34:in `call'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:406:in `raw_execute'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:384:in `execute'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:171:in `switchToDefaultContent'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.2.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:68:in `default_content'
from auto.rb:25:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea why I can't catch this exception. Using `rescue Exception` **should** catch everything, but as you can see my script still crashes.

I have also found sources that say you must catch the timeout explicitly so I also tried:

`rescue Timeout::Error`

without any luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated on this one.

**Ruby version: ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553)**

**OS: MacOS Snow Leopard 10.6.8 64-bit**

**Selenium Webdriver version: 2.2.0**

Comment: Ruby is typically indented with two spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file 'timeout.rb' in Ruby's standard library defines:

```
module Timeout
  # Raised by Timeout#timeout when the block times out.
  class Error < RuntimeError
```

So what you need to `rescue` is not `Timeout::Exception` but rather `Timeout::Error` or more generically `RuntimeError`. Then it should work.

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a typo, fixing that now. I was using Timeout::Error and that still didn't work. Just tried RuntimeError as well and it didn't catch it either. Any thoughts on what else might be causing this to not work?

Comment: Which one is the line 'auto.rb:25' exactly - is it `driver.navigate.to line`?

Comment: Yikes, I must be tired at work today. It's actually the driver.switch_to.default_content line. Moving that line into the begin/rescue block which explicitly catches Timeout::Error works!